# How do I compare headers from HttpContext.Request/Response with those of HttpRequestMessage.Request/Response?

Tags: c#, http-headers, c#-10.0

I am annoyed with the `HttpContext` class that uses different types for the request and response than `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage`. The HttpContext class uses `IHeaderDictionary` for the headers while the other classes use `HttpRequestHeaders` and `HttpResponseHeaders` for the headers. (Both are derived from `HttpHeaders`.)
My problem is that I'm working on a Web API that needs to extract headers from the context and pass these headers onwards while using `HttpClient.SendAsync(...)` to call another site. (Yes, site! Not another service!)
What I want is a simple function that can copy the headers from the context request to the new request. And after the request is executed I want to use *the same function* to copy the headers from the response into my context response. This cannot be done because the headers are different types.

The types involved are:
`interface IHeaderDictionary : IDictionary<string, StringValues>{}`
`class HttpHeaders : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>`
So the challenge is that we have a dictionary with a `StringValues` value versus an enumerable with an enumerable as value. Comparing apples and pears, basically...
So how do I make *a single function* that can assign headers from one list to another?

Comment: And yes, I can just make two functions, but then I have code between both functions that are basically copy/paste. Or make a third function. Or even more. That solves it for now, but I am copying headers to headers so that should be possible in an easier way!

Comment: What's wrong with two methods? You can create a single method that has internal type casting and checks, but the signature for the method wouldn't be type-safe. I think you should keep two simple, easy to read methods and call it good.

Comment: @Kit There's nothing wrong with two methods, except I end up violating the DRY rule. There are some validations and modifications that need to be done to these headers while copying them. And yes, internal typecasting would not be pretty. But as I said, I'm basically copying headers to headers so why it this so hard?

Comment: The "why is it so hard" part comes down to time and people I suspect. Meaning, there's a fair bit of time between the implementations, and a fair number of people as well. If you could compress both, it would probably end up being a single implementation or at least a more compatible one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing that I could come up with is partially DRY, and is mostly typesafe.

```cs
void Copy<T, U>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>> from, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, U>> to)
    where T : IEnumerable<string>
    where U : IEnumerable<string>
{
    if (to is IHeaderDictionary headerDictionary)
        foreach (var x in from)
            headerDictionary.Add(x.Key, new StringValues(x.Value.ToArray()));
    else
    if (to is HttpHeaders httpHeaders)
        foreach (var x in from)
            httpHeaders.Add(x.Key, new List<string?>(x.Value));
}
```

This method assumes both collections actually already exist. If you have to create the target collection and return it, the method would get way more complex, and you'd lose the ability to infer the type parameters at the call site.

To prove that the code can actually be compiled, I created a controller with a variation of `Copy` that takes nullable parameters. (This is just to keep all of it in a single place).

```cs
[ApiController]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    void Copy<T, U>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>>? from, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, U>>? to)
        where T : IEnumerable<string>
        where U : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        if (from == null || to == null)
            return;

        if (to is IHeaderDictionary headerDictionary)
            foreach (var x in from)
                headerDictionary.Add(x.Key, new StringValues(x.Value.ToArray()));
        else
        if (to is HttpHeaders httpHeaders)
            foreach (var x in from)
                httpHeaders.Add(x.Key, new List<string?>(x.Value));
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        // in real life, these come from somewhere else and won't be null
        HttpRequestHeaders? requestHeaders = null;
        HttpRequestHeaders? responseHeaders = null;

        // actual types are inferred. yay!
        Copy(HttpContext.Request.Headers, requestHeaders);
        Copy(requestHeaders, HttpContext.Request.Headers);
        Copy(HttpContext.Response.Headers, responseHeaders);
        Copy(responseHeaders, HttpContext.Response.Headers);
        Copy(requestHeaders, responseHeaders);
        Copy(responseHeaders, requestHeaders);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good enough. :)